# Factorially closed subrings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, factorization, unique-factorization-domains

[Lemma 3.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01508v1.pdf) says: Let $A$ be a UFD. Let $R \subseteq A$ be a subring of $A$ such that 
$R^* = A^*$.
The following conditions are equivalent:
(i) Every irreducible element of $R$ remains irreducible in $A$.
(ii) $R$ is factorially closed in $A$, namely, if $x,y \in A$ satisfy 
$xy \in R - {0}$, then $x,y \in R$.

**My question:**

Do we have a similar result to the above if we replace the assumption that $A$ is a UFD by a weaker assumption?

For example, by the assumption that $A$ is atomic (=every non-zero non-unit element of $A$ has a factorization into irreducible elements) and every non-zero non-unit element of $A$ has only a finite number of nonassociate irreducible divisors. See also [this paper](http://www.lohar.com/researchpdf/Factorization_in_integral_domains.pdf).

Perhaps we should add to the weaker assumption an additional assumption in order to get a similar result to the above? For example, $A=R[a]$, where $a \in A$ is algebraic over $R$ (and also an irreducible element of $A$?) , or $R \subseteq A$ is an integral extension.

I would appreciate any relevant idea.

Comment: You might email Dan Anderson (at the University of Iowa).  He is an expert on these types of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think I will wait a little to see if I get an answer here, and then I will probably email Anderson.